# how to access server using SFTP without password in python language

Tags: python, paramiko, ssh-keys

It is code for passwordless connection through paramiko
when I run this code it shows RSA private file is invalid
what it is and how to fix this problem

please explain meaning of third last line
how to generate the key in windows
i am providing the code below please help

Code:

```
#get IP and username for remote access
IP = input("Enter host_server IP: ").split()
username = input("Enter username: ").split()


#create a file on host_server for file
file_a = open(date+"file.txt", "a") #ignore the date variable
file = str(date+"file.txt")
import paramiko
import os
privatekeyfile = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile)
ssh.connect(IP[0], username = user[0], pkey = mykey)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an **SSH key pair**, which consists of a private and public key.

The private key should be stored safely on your own computer, by default in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` under Linux, or `C:\users\your_name\.ssh\id_rsa` under Windows, but you may use a different file name in the same directory so you know which key it is later on (you might need to create more SSH keys in the future). This is the file used by paramiko.

The public key should be copied to the server. How this is done depends on your setup. If it's your own SFTP server, you can probably do that using SSH or SCP. It's also possible that you can do it through a web interface. Consult the manual of your SFTP server/service for more information.

The SSH key pair can be created using `ssh-keygen`. On Linux this is probably already installed. In Windows you'll probably have it if you have PuTTY installed.

Search for "generate ssh key pair" or something like that to get more information about how to create the keys if you don't know how to do it. There are many sites that describe how to do that.